# How to make a multi value parameter independent from 2 dependent cascading multi value parameter?

Tags: reporting-services

I have 3 drop down parameters D,E,F. 1 value only is possible to select in each of the 3 parameters. 2 are dependent on each other and 1 is independent from those 2. But all 3 are still dependent on parameter A OR B OR C . total 6 parameters are required.
Dataset1:

```
select name,birthdate,id,sex 
               from patient
           where name = @D
           and (number = @A OR(@No IS NULL))
           and (dateofbirth =@B OR (@DOB IS NULL))
           and (id =@C OR (@ID IS NULL))
```

Dataset_Dropdownparameter_D:

```
select DISTINCT firstname
from patientNAW
where dateofbirth =@B
or id =@C
or number = @A
```

Dataset_Dropdownparameter E:

```
select DISTINCT name
from patientNAW
where number = @A 
or id =@C
or dateofbirth =@B
```

Dataset_Dropdownparameter F:

```
select DISTINCT Marriedname
    from patientNAW
    where dateofbirth =@B
    or number = @A 
    or id =@C
```

[Please click on this to see picture Parameter A,B,C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ6jU.png)

Same has been setup for B and C. These are just typed in.

The primary key is Number. i don't want to show a single patient for example if i have a twins i can run the report by only inserting the birthdate and name.

And parameter F(Marriedname) doesn't depend on parameter name. For example i should be able to type the birthdate and i get a dropdown of names with that birthdate.

[screenshot of the parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF21k.png)

Comment: It hard to work out what the actual problem is. Can you edit your question (rather than add a comment) and show examples of the parameter values and how the dependencies are setup.Also clarify if these are mutli value or not, you said they are multi value but also said `1 value only is possible to select in each of the 3 parameters` which sounds like they should be single value parameters.

Comment: Hi Alan. Please see edit question.

Comment: Can you edit it a little more and include how parameters A, B and C are entered, are these just typed in? What is the primary key for the patient record, ID or Number maybe? Do you only want to show a single patient record in the report?

Comment: Please see edit question.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your question but not testing anything, I think it might be as simple as editing the dataset query to

```
select name,birthdate,id,sex 
               from patient
           where name = @D
           and (number = @A OR @A IS NULL)
           and (dateofbirth =@B OR @B IS NULL)
           and (id =@C OR @C IS NULL)
```

You need to test if the parameter is null, and if it is ignore it but you were using some other parameters (not sure where they came from)

Comment: I'm using that query as my main dataset. And for the dropdown parameters D,E,F are they correct? Because for example if i type the date of birth i get a dropdown in Name and Married name. If i select a married name i can't view the report i have to slect the name and firstname after that i can click view report. What i want is type birthofdate in and select marriedname and run the report.

Comment: Hi alan, please see second picture screenshot of the parameters.See screenshots of the parameters(click on the text to see picture)

Comment: I'll try to look at this soon but really busy at work at the moment.

Comment: Okay alan it would be helpfull if it's possible to fix it